# java.nio.file.Path error with VSS (Volume Shadow Copy) paths

Tags: java, windows, unc, volume-shadow-service

Using VSS, I've created a volume snapshot and can successfully access files on it:

```
C:\> type \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\Users\Eric\Desktop\test.txt
test text 1/2
test text 2/2
```

When I try to access the same file from java using `java.io.File` it works fine.  However I am unable to convert it to a `java.nio.file.Path` by calling `toPath` like this:

```
File file = newFile(vssPath)
Path path = file.toPath()
```

Doing so results in an exception trace.  This is a [known issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165748) for OpenJDK and I get the same result with java 1.8.91:

```
STACKTRACE:: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal character [?] in path at index 2: \\?    \GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\Users\qa\Desktop\lock_full.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.nextSlash(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.toPath(Unknown Source)
```

Since I can't get a `Path` there are certain APIs I'm unable to use, for example `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel` which can only be instantiated with a `Path`.

Is there any alternative syntax for accessing the shadow copy file that won't run afoul of this JDK limitation?  The OpenJDK ticket linked above recommends just omitting the long-UNC prefix (`\\?`) but I haven't found any variation of this that seems to be legal.  For example the following all fail:

```
    C:\> type \\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\Users\Eric\Desktop\test.txt
    C:\> type \\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\Users\Eric\Desktop\test.txt
    C:\> type \\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\Users\Eric\Desktop\test.txt
```

If there's no variant path I can use to call `toPath()` then is there some other way I could acquire a `java.nio.file.Path` that doesn't run afoul of the parser limitation?

Comment: I think that Alan is saying that dropping the prefix might work *in Java*.  It certainly won't work from the command line.  (The idea appears to be that Java will automatically put the prefix back when calling the Windows API.  Although I don't quite understand how it can tell when that's the right thing to do.)

Comment: Perhaps java will correctly add the prefix when required because the length of the path is greater than MAX_PATH?  That would make sense but of course doesn't help for working with VSS.

Comment: I considered that, but the OP at the linked ticket said that it solved their problem, and they didn't *seem* to be dealing with long paths.  Hard to be certain though.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a timely workaround, my team discussed:

1. create our own implementation of `java.nio.file.Path` (or find one in some other library)
2. change code to avoid the use of `java.nio.file.Path`

... and we settled on #2.  #1 would be a more general workaround should probably be the accepted answer if somebody ever does it and shares.